# How do I retrieve a PDF page's boxes info?

Tags: linux, pdf, metadata, pdf-reader

I know PDFs have various "boxes" defined for their pages: [Media box, bleed box, art box etc.](https://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/PDF_Boxes_:_mediabox,_cropbox,_bleedbox,_trimbox,_artbox). But - typical PDF viewers in Linux don't seem to show these boxes, nor list their dimensions and positions in any "page properties" or "file properties" dialogs.

Suppose I have a one-page PDF. How can I determine those boxes' sizes and dimensions?

I don't mind using the command-line of course.

Note: Assume a reasonably-modern Linux distribution.

Comment: I don't think those are viewable with PDF readers. The whole idea of the file format is that you can read it on paper or digitally and the layout stays. PDF readers are used to view the end product. They don't need to know anything about those boxes. On the other hand they're of vital importance for layout design applications like InDesign or Scribus and digital press machines. A PDF editor might also understand them, if I remember right Acrobat Pro does.

Comment: @Peregrino69: At least some of these boxes are listed explicitly in the PDF file: There are `/MediaBox[...]` and `/FontBBox[...]` commands, or elements.

Comment: Yes, they have to be, as digital press needs them, and PDF is the format you input into it. What I'm saying is PDF viewers need no knowledge about them.

Comment: Typically a PDF viewer will use the /CropBox, if available, or the /MediaBox if not. So it won't look at the /ArtBox, /TrimBox, or /BleedBox. You can display the boxes with `cpdf -page-info in.pdf`. If a box is missing, it is shown as missing. Nothing is substituted. You can use `cpdf -show-boxes in.pdf -o out.pdf` to provide a visual representation of the boxes superimposed on the page, which can be useful.

Comment: @johnwhitington: That sounds like an answer. Please also say a few more words about `cpdf`.

Comment: a lot of the useful info is available from pdftotext utility

Answer (score 2):

#### How do I retrieve a PDF page's boxes info?

Use `pdfinfo`:

```
pdfinfo -box filename.pdf
```

> `-box`
> Prints the page box bounding boxes: MediaBox, CropBox, BleedBox, TrimBox, and ArtBox.

Source: [pdfinfo(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdfinfo)

Comment: I just tested it, updated my answer. Unfortunately it's sadly lacking in the sense OP is asking. I also found an inaccuracy in the `man` page... "Prints the page box bounding boxes" should be "Prints the dimensions of page box bounding boxes"...

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving this info isn't possible with a PDF viewer.

The mentioned boxes are called **boundary boxes** or page boxes.

- **BBox** is the smallest rectangle that can enclose all the content on the page. Ideally a line drawn around the BBox would touch the edge of the visible content on all sides of the page.
- **CropBox** defines the region a PDF viewer is expected to display or print. This isn't used in prepress, and the [GWG industry association](https://gwg.org/associations/) recommends not using it at all.
- **MediaBox** specifies the width and the height of the page. Average person understands this to be the size of the actual printed page, but in prepress the page is slightly larger to accommodate bleed<sup>1</sup>, crop marks, file names, creation date/time etc.

The last three boxes are used only in the printing press.

- **Trimbox** defines the intended dimensions of the finished printed page
- **BleedBox** defines the region to which the page contents need to be clipped when output in a production environment
- **ArtBox** was originally intended to indicate the area covered by the artwork of the page, but isn't used for that. On a PDF page containing an ad it can be used to define the location of the ad. When creating printed material this is used as a safety zone, for example to prevent text being printed so close to the page edge that it's difficult to read when a book is produced.

As PDF viewer only displays the innermost area of the entire page, it doesn't have knowledge of these boxes. They have to exist in the PDF sent to a digital press, consequently page layout applications such as InDesign must be aware of them, but they don't show up at all in PDFs produced by other means (exported from a text editor like Word, documents scanned to PDF etc.).

<sup>1</sup>*Bleed is the section of artwork that extends beyond the line where the paper is cut. This is to ensure an image that's supposed to extend at the edge of paper always does regardless of minute variances in the trimming.*

Sources:

- [Adobe ISO 32000-1:2008 Specification 1.4.11.2.1](https://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/PDF_Boxes_:_mediabox,_cropbox,_bleedbox,_trimbox,_artbox#14.11.2_Page_Boundaries)
- https://www.prepressure.com/pdf/basics/page-boxes
- https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/finding-page-boundaries/

UPDATE

Thanks for David Postill for bringing `pdfinfo` to my attention. I tested it with different materials and found it to be limited.

- User guide of a synth I own. Created with PageMaker, produced with Distiller. It shows the dimensions of the boxes, but they're all equal to the page size i.e. the TrimBox dimensions.
- 2 digital editions of magazines. One created with iTextPDF, the other with Adobe Acrobat 21.7 and Distiller 21.0. As both contain edge-to-edge images, the 3 boxes used for press are certainly used. Similarly to above dimensions default to TrimBox.
- User Guide of a StarTech device downloaded from StarTech site. Created with InDesign CC 2018.1, intended for printing as well as digital viewing, produced by Adobe PDF Library i.e. exported directly from ID. Boxes not shown at all.
- IEEE standard downloaded from GetIEEE. Created with Debenu Quick PDF Library 11.15. Box dimensions default to TrimBox.
- USB Dev class definition for Audio Devices 1988, downloaded from USB.org. Created with MS Word & Adobe PDF Writer 3.0. As above dimensions default to TrimBox.
- Sitecom external drive datasheet. Created with InDesign CS / Adobe PDF Library 6.0, i.e. directly exported from ID. As above, dimensions default to TrimBox.
- Lipsum document I exported from LibreOffice Writer. As above, dimensions default to TrimBox. This I didn't expect to see at all. With a quick search I found out that Writer actually has [no capacity to allow bleed](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/does-writer-export-to-pdfs-with-cut-lines/56297) so the boxes don't actually exist in any functional capacity. I suspect they are there just to ensure the PDF adheres to ISO 32000 standard.
- A few other random PDFs created by diverse means. If box dimensions are shown at all they default to TrimBox.

Conclusion:

In this sense `pdfinfo` can be useful in a very limited number of situations, but when analyzing an actual finalized / published PDF:s it's useless. In all documents the dimensions (when showing) equal the TrimBox dimensions. I have no doubt that if I had an original PDF intended to be fed to a digital press, it'd show the actual dimensions of the boxes.

Even with an original document it can only show the dimensions of the boxes, but not the positioning. If the file is for example a poster, it can be safely assumed all boxes are centered in the page. However if it's a book, the BleedBox must be positioned closer to the outer edge of the page as the inner edge must have sufficient space to allow binding w/o obstructing the content.

Comment: `pdfinfo -box filename.pdf` does the trick - see my answer.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidPostill! Always nice to have new tool in my toolbox :-)

Comment: Thank you for the super-detailed explanation. What do you mean, though, by "published" PDFs? Suppose I created a documented in some app like LibreOffice or Inkscape and saved it as a PDF; is that "published"? I also don't understand what you  mean by "used only in the printing press"; are these supposed to be specified inside a PDF file, or are these just printing process terms?

Comment: @einpoklum Well, not until you make it publicly available :-D I'm referring to materials like manuals, magazines, books... but thanks, I modified my answer a bit :-)